# Jsoup - Search table by cell entry, return next cell data

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have the following embedded html I am trying to parse:

```
<table class="repeated table name" width="100%"
    <tbody>
        <tr class="label">
          <td>Search Item</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row1">
           <td>Return Item </td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

The  entry for Search Item is consistent, so I want to search for this entry, but I would like to return the entry in the following row, Return Item.

Can anyone please help with this?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be this:

```
Element els = doc.select("td:containsOwn(search item)").parents().first();
Element nextSibling = els.nextElementSibling();

System.out.println(nextSibling.select("td").text());
```

I'm assuming that a more elegant approach exists, but this gets the job done.